# How would you dynamically change an SSRS body background image based on field value that may change from page to page?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report where I need a watermark to show only on certain pages. The field that the watermark is based on may be different from page to page or group to group. The problem I'm having is that whatever the watermark is set to the first page, it remains throughout the report since I am setting the body background image. Any idea how I can do this?

Body Background Image Value:

```
=IIF(Fields!MilitaryPartAlert.Value = "** Military Part **","MilitaryWatermark","")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to set the background image elsewhere.  I would suggest adding a list item to your report, stretching it across the entire report, and add all of your report items into the first cell.  Apply your grouping to the list item and the expression you posted above, and it should apply to each group instance or page.  Though, I might recommend a small adjustment to the expression.

```
=IIF(Fields!MilitaryPartAlert.Value = "** Military Part **","MilitaryWatermark", Nothing)
```